# Why DotnetOpenID have not implemented the logout from Openid Provider?

Tags: dotnetopenauth, logout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to logout from Relying Party?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026359/how-to-logout-from-relying-party)

Why DotnetOpenID have not implemented the logout from Openid Provider ?

There current version is DotNetOpenId-2.5.5.9153 and DotNetOpenAuth-3.1.0.9122

Are they planning to implement logout in next version ?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by logout from the OpenID Provider?  Are you saying that OpenID Providers cannot log users out of their own web sites?  That if a user logs out of an OP they should be logged out of RPs automatically?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say this is more or less a duplicate of your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026359/how-to-logout-from-relying-party).  I've posted an answer there.  In short, DotNetOpenId doesn't implement single-sign out because the OpenID spec doesn't explain how it would be done.  No OpenID library offers single-sign out because it doesn't exist.

For instance, a user probably wants to sign out of the RP, the OP, and all the other RPs that were signed into during his session when he steps away from the computer.  But exactly how to interact with so many web sites at once from a single user gesture just hasn't been fully figured out yet.