# Logout with gmail account through c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, dotnetopenauth

i am using DotNetOpenAuth dll for logging my sample application through gmail authentication through c# .net.

I successfully login in my gmail account then i want to logout from my gmail account. I referred  this link for login in gmail accout.

[Login with gmail account through c# .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354278/login-with-gmail-account-through-c-sharp-net)

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026359/how-to-logout-from-relying-party

Comment: Thanks Srinivas , this link useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

From this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1026384/237838

> I think you are mistaking the Relying Party and the OpenID Provider. Using StackOverflow as an example, SO is the Relying Party and other sites (e.g. Google) are the OpenID Provider(s).
>
> The Relying Party (e.g. SO) has no say in when the OpenID Provider (e.g. Google) chooses to "forget" the user for their own purposes.

DotNetOpenId doesn't offer this feature because OpenID itself doesn't have this feature in its spec.